# Can't Consume Web Services

Tags: php, maps

I've been trying to access Google Maps web services or even Yahoo Maps using PHP. When I run it, I get nothing. All the HTML and prints come out but absolutely nothing from Google service.

When I gave the code to my friend to run it on his local PC, it showed up fine and was working showing the map. But it seems I have trouble here at university.

Is it because I am behind a proxy? What could be the issue? Also the host can't be accessed outside the university.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: seems to get stuck when using simplexml_load_file

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the WSDL for Google Maps? And maybe provide a sample of the code? I'm not seeing anywhere in Google Code where Map API is offered as a web service.

Comment: We can't help you without any code samples.

Comment: You gave the code to your friend but you won't show us? Thought we had something here?

Comment: Anthony: Google Maps API is a JavaScript API, there is no SOAP or WSDL.

Comment: Tarik: What do you mean by "get stuck"? It hangs or logs an error? Please be more specific.

Comment: So it's not consumed by PHP? That could be the problem...

Answer (score 3):

If it is getting stuck on `simplexml_load_file`, and you are trying to use `simplexml_load_file` to get a remote file, and your University (like mine) has PHP in safe mode, this will fail. You can't get remote files like that in safe-mode. You should get the XML via `cURL`, and then use `simplexml_load_string`.

This would also explain why your friend could do it and you couldn't.